# How do I obtain the browser's previous page Url that redirected me to my application

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I require the URL of the previous page from where the user is redirected to my application.

I tried using request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
But it returns the value as null.

The user is required to bypass a login page before he enters my Application.
Also request.getHeader("Referer") is blocked by Firewalls.
please suggest a way to obtain the previous page URL for Statistics of my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to maintain the state of user by using session tracking as we are using HTTP protocol. You can use cookies, Hidden Form Field, URL Rewriting, HttpSession.
I think this will help. You can also share your code to get the  better idea... Thanks